# How to increase the size dots in a bar chart?

Tags: charts, size, spotfire

I have a requirement where I have 3 columns, 1 for Project Task, 2.Time Consumed in seconds and 3. the errors occured in each task.

I want to create a chart where x axis is project task, y with time consumed and I wanted the errors indicated as dots inside the chart?

Can we change the bar or line to just dots in the chart? Also can I increase the size of the dots based on Sum(Errors) for eg 1 error small size, 2 errors slightly bigger than 1 etc

Answer (score 2):

you cannot have dot markers on a bar chart; otherwise it wouldn't be a bar chart :)

however you can do all of these things in a scatter plot! the easiest method is probably to right click your bar chart and *Change Visualization to...* > *Scatter Plot*.

for the size, there is a "Size By" dimension that you can set to `Sum([Errors])` (or anything else).

Comment: But I believe we cannot customize the size based on a range like for 0 it should be smaller or 1 bit larger for 2 larger than 1 like that

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean. The Size By dimension does literally that :) if you’re having trouble configuring, maybe a screenshot will be helpful